# jQuery Validation with inline-block errors

Tags: jquery, validation

I have my validation script working fine, but I am using inline-block errors and hiding them. When the jQuery Validation plugin switches them back I guess it uses show which throws in an inline display:block or display:inline style depending on the tag. What I need to do is have it display:inline-block. Is there a way I can attach a css selector to each field after jQuery Validate shows the errors?

Here's a snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#applicationForm").validate({
    errorElement: 'span',   
    errorContainer: $('.error'),
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        emailVerify: {
            required:true,
            email:true,
            equalTo: "#email"
        }
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you need done, but you can override how the Validation plugin deals with showing errors by implementing the `showErrors` function.

The default one looks essentially like this:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    for (var i = 0; this.errorList[i]; i++) {
        var error = this.errorList[i];
        this.showLabel(error.element, error.message);

        this.settings.highlight && this.settings.highlight.call(this, error.element, this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass);
    }
    if (this.errorList.length) {
        this.toShow = this.toShow.add(this.containers);
    }
    if (this.settings.success) {
        for (var i = 0; this.successList[i]; i++) {
            this.showLabel(this.successList[i]);
        }
    }
    if (this.settings.unhighlight) {
        for (var i = 0, elements = this.validElements(); elements[i]; i++) {
            this.settings.unhighlight.call(this, elements[i], this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass);
        }
    }
    this.toHide = this.toHide.not(this.toShow);
    this.hideErrors();
    this.addWrapper(this.toShow).show();
}
```

It sounds like your preference would be to change the last line to something else.

It may be simpler to implement the `invalidHandler` and have that function find the error elements and change the display property on them appropriately.

Comment: showErrors worked, but invalidHandler did not. Adding the css inline-block turned all the errors on right away. Pasting this function into my validator options accomplishes what I want by adding this.addWrapper(this.toShow).css({'display' : 'inline-block'}); to the last line. I still wish there was a cleaner way to to this, but happy it's working the way I need it too. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed a few questions around SO that required fiddling with the 'default' showErrors functionality.  I think to some extent, it just can't be all things to all people, but for your particular case, I could see adding options to deal with **how** to show/hide.